# How can MySQL dates be used in C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, date

I'm using connector/c++ to build some MySQL C++ programs, and one thing I've run into is using dates. I can't seem to find this anywhere. What would be the best way to use MySQL dates in C++?

More specifically, is there a date class or data type that can store MySQL dates that can be inserted into prepared statements in a method similar to setInt() or setString()?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650715/c-standard-date-time-class) illuminating. Boost and MFC have a date and time class, but standard C++ does not. You'll have to do the conversion yourself, though.