# c++ Appropriate function return type to return datetime?

Tags: c++, datetime, date, time, return-type

Coming from C# it was quite common for me to write a class that might have a DateTime as a return type (or parameter).  Now I'm programming in C++. What is the appropriate data type to use as a method return value returning a datetime value (time_t, tm struct, [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/date_time.html), something else?)  E.g.:

```
class Customer
{
   ...
   ? GetDateTimeCreated() const;
   void SetLastContactDateTime(? date);
   ...
}
```

Also, what about accepting date/times as function parameters?

Comment: `struct tm` is only used for formatting.  C++ doesn't really have any standards for date/time besides `time_t`, `Boost.Date_Time`, and whatever your platform gives you.

Comment: time_t is the appropriate return type for a time value. %man 2 time to find out about time_t.

Comment: possible another stackoverflow post will help out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650715/c-standard-date-time-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing a library, and the datetime value will exposed via the API, then I'd use `time_t` so that users of the library are not forced to use Boost.

As was pointed out, `struct tm` is used for formatting a `time_t`. You don't normally want to be passing those around.

If your program already uses Boost, and you like the convenience of Boost.DateTime, then by all means use Boost.DateTime. If I remember correctly, `boost::posix_time::ptime` is just a wrapper around two 64-bit integers, so it's lightweight enough to pass around by value.

If you're using C++11 features, then you might want to use `std::chrono::time_point` from [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono). If you're still on C++03, you can use [Boost.Chrono](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/chrono.html), which aims to implement the C++11 time facilities. By using Boost.Chrono, you should be able to more easily make the switch to C++11 in the future. Chrono doesn't have as many features as Boost.DateTime, but it's a step up from plain old `time_t`.

If you need sub-second precision, then Boost.DateTime or Chrono is the way to go.

Comment: Chrono `time_point`s are not a good replacement for `System.DateTime`, because they don't include any facilities for (Gregorian) date.

Answer (score 2):

The `boost::posix_time::ptime` from Boost.Date_Time is modern and full-featured, and is the closest C++ analog to the C# `System.DateTime`.

`boost::posix_time::ptime` and `System.DateTime` are both very lightweight structs which just wrap an unsigned integer, so they are good function return values.

One slight difference: `boost::posix_time::ptime` has microsecond precision (by default, but precision can be increased with template parameter), and `System.DateTime` has 100-nanosecond precision.