# Comparing 2 dates in c++

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there is any relatively easy and short date comparison functions in C++. 
My dates are of type `char*`, and have the following format: `DD\MM\YYYY`

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650715/c-standard-date-time-class . I wrote my own date class to do those manipulations. You can also do it easily.

Comment: Also check out C++11s new *chrono* header that has support for some date and time utilities.

Comment: Backslashes, not forward slashes?

Comment: Is the format a requirement? ISO standard dates, YYYY-MM-DD, can be compared with the normal string compare.

Comment: yes, this is format the date is given, DD\MM\YYYY.

Answer (score 7):

Parsing is usually done on streams, not strings, but you can use a `stringstream`.

```
std::istringstream date_s( "04\\10\\1984" );
struct tm date_c;
date_s >> std::get_time( &date_c, "%d\\%m\\%Y" );
std::time_t seconds = std::mktime( & date_c );
```

Now you can compare seconds using `<` to determine which was earlier.

Note, [`std::get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) is new in C++11. It is defined in terms of `strptime`, which is from POSIX but not part of the C99 standard. You can use [`strptime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html) if a C++11 library is not available. If you're brave, you can also use the `std::time_get` facet… it's ugly though.

If you don't want to know anything about the dates other than which is earlier, you can use `std::lexicographical_compare`. It would be a one-liner but the function name is so long.

```
// return true if the date string at lhs is earlier than rhs
bool date_less_ddmmyyyy( char const *lhs, char const *rhs ) {
    // compare year
    if ( std::lexicographical_compare( lhs + 6, lhs + 10, rhs + 6, rhs + 10 ) )
        return true;
    if ( ! std::equal( lhs + 6, lhs + 10, rhs + 6 ) )
        return false;
    // if years equal, compare month
    if ( std::lexicographical_compare( lhs + 3, lhs + 5, rhs + 3, rhs + 5 ) )
        return true;
    if ( ! std::equal( lhs + 3, lhs + 5, rhs + 3 ) )
        return false;
    // if months equal, compare days
    return std::lexicographical_compare( lhs, lhs + 2, rhs, rhs+2 );
}
```

See also [how to convert datetime to unix timestamp in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002542/how-to-convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-in-c) .

Comment: For the std::get_time example, in Visual Studio 2013 I needed to first memset the tm struct to zero's in order to get mktime to work. For example: memset(&date_c, 0, sizeof(date_c));

Answer (score 2):

If this is really a fixed format, you can do it with simple C string comparison

```
int date_cmp(const char *d1, const char *d2)
{
    int rc;
    // compare years
    rc = strncmp(d1 + 6, d2 + 6, 4);
    if (rc != 0)
        return rc;

    // compare months
    rc = strncmp(d1 + 3, d2 + 3, 2);
    if (rc != 0)
        return rc;

    // compare days
    return strncmp(d1, d2, 2);
}
```

This works like [`strncmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncmp). It returns a value less than 0, if `d1` is earlier than `d2`, 0 if both are the same date, and a value greater than 0, if `d1` is later than `d2`.

Another approach would be to convert it with [`strptime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) and [`mktime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime) to `time_t` and compare these with [`difftime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/difftime)

```
struct tm tm;
time_t t1, t2;
strptime(d1, "%d\\%m\\%Y", &tm);
t1 = mktime(&tm);
// do the same with d2
double diff = difftime(t1, t2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the numeric data from the string. Worst case scenario is a bunch of loops and string to integer conversion functions.

You can do it easily with sscanf and sprintf. If you're used to [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) and [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) then this is simple to understand, and you can easily adapt it to other cases. There are no secret magic function calls.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char* date1 = "9\\12\\2012"; 
    char* date2 = "6\\11\\2013"; 

    int day1,month1,year1;
    int day2,month2,year2;

    sscanf(date1,"%d\\%d\\%d",&day1,&month1,&year1); //reads the numbers
    sscanf(date2,"%d\\%d\\%d",&day2,&month2,&year2); //from the string

    if (year1<year2 || month1<month2 || day1<day2) //compares 2 dates
    {
        printf("date1 < date2\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("date1 >= date2\n");
    }

    char newdate[15];

    sprintf(newdate,"%d\\%d\\%d",13,2,1998); //make a date string from numbers
    printf("%s\n",newdate);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i have only one ' \ ' between the D\M\Y and not two

Comment: the second one is an escaping slash

Comment: I hope no one used this since the date comparison is wrong. It should be `if (year1 != year2) { return year1 < year2; }` etc.

Answer (score 1):

How about an efficient solution?  Your fixed size dates only require 8 chars  if you ignore the slashes.  So with a little shifting and byte swapping you can compare them as 64 bit ints.  This is faster than comparing as strings.

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
typedef unsigned __int16 U2;
typedef unsigned __int32 U4;
typedef unsigned __int64 U8;
#define bswap2 _byteswap_ushort
#define bswap4 _byteswap_ulong
#define bswap8 _byteswap_uint64

const int YYYYMMDD = 0;
const int YYYY_MM_DD = 1;
const int DDMMYYYY = 2;
const int DD_MM_YYYY = 3;

// compiler will optimize the if's out.
template <int FMT>
U8 DateToInt(char* sz) {
    if (FMT == YYYYMMDD) {
        return bswap8(*(U8*)sz);
    }
    if (FMT == YYYY_MM_DD) {
        U4 y = *(U4*)sz, m = *(U2*)(sz + 5), d = *(U2*)(sz + 8);
        return ((U8)bswap4(y) << 32) | (bswap2(m) << 16) | bswap2(d);
    }
    if (FMT == DD_MM_YYYY) {
        U4 y = *(U4*)(sz + 6), m = *(U2*)(sz + 3), d = *(U2*)sz;
        return ((U8)bswap4(y) << 32) | (bswap2(m) << 16) | bswap2(d);
    }
}

template<int FMT1, int FMT2 = FMT1>
__int64 CompareDate(char* sz1, char* sz2) {
    return DateToInt<FMT1>(sz1) - DateToInt<FMT2>(sz2);
}

void main() {
    cout << CompareDate<YYYYMMDD>("20151025", "20151026") << endl;
    cout << CompareDate<YYYYMMDD>("20151025", "20151024") << endl;
    cout << CompareDate<YYYYMMDD, YYYY_MM_DD>("20151025", "2015/10/26") << endl;
    cout << CompareDate<YYYYMMDD, YYYY_MM_DD>("20151025", "2015/10/24") << endl;
    cout << CompareDate<YYYYMMDD, DD_MM_YYYY>("20151025", "26/10/2015") << endl;
    cout << CompareDate<YYYYMMDD, DD_MM_YYYY>("20151025", "24/10/2015") << endl;
}
```

output

```
-1
1
-1
1
-1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem and just came up with an easy solution.  You can serialize the date with the following function.  Then compare the serial numbers.  Greater serial number means greater date.

Serial # = YYYY ×100,000,000 + MM ×1,000,000 + DD*10,000 + hour * 100 + min *1

Ex: compare 12/1/2023 00:00 with 11/30/20223 23:59
12/1/2023 00:00-> 2023*100,000,000 + 12×1,000,000 + 31*10,000 +0*100 + 0*1 = 202,312,010,000
11/30/2023 23:59-> 2023 * 100,000,000 + 11*1,000,000 + 30*10,000 + 23*100 + 59 = 202,311,302,359

202,312,010,000 > 202,311,302,359 and hence 12/1/2023 00:00 is greater date.

This should work for all dates in question.

If you want to measure smaller increments, lets say  seconds, start the multiplier factor of the smallest increment (in this case, seconds as 1) and then increase the multiplier factor by 100 for each next unit up.
ex: for time with milliseconds:
1/1/2024 01:30:45 ... MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS

2024x10,000,000,000 + 1x100,000,000 + 1x1,000,000 + 1x10,000 + 30x100 + 45x1 = serial number.

You can then compare the serial numbers.