# How to manage dates in C++

Tags: c++, date, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ standard date/time class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650715/c-standard-date-time-class)

### The question

How can I manage dates in C++?

By that, I mean - is there something in the standard library I can use (similar to `Date`/`Calendar` in Java), should I make my own class, or should I use some 3rd party library (îf so, which one?).

Basically, what I need is to be able to store/retrieve data related to dates (time, day, month, year, weekday) and compare date objects between them (for sorting).

### What I've already tried

Well, I have made a simple `Calendar` class that mimics the behavior of Java's `Calendar` class... But I'm having trouble dealing with leap years (well, that's OK, but it messes up my week days), week days, and that kind of stuff.

I have also seen [old posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650715/c-standard-date-time-class) (2 years+) on SO about it, but I'm wondering if there is anything more recent.

Comment: @CarlNorum that is quite an old question and it might deserve an answer to say that either it's changed in C++11 or hasn't.

Comment: @CarlNorum As Seth Carnegie said, I would like to have a more recent answer if there is one.. I'll make that clear in the question.

Comment: I assume you want pure C++ and not some C++ framework.

Comment: @drescherjm I actually don't mind. I want to evaluate different alternatives. SL is better, but 3rd party framework will do too.

Comment: If you are using Qt framework there are QDate and QTime classes. Boost also has a broad variety of date and time classes. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/date_time.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt framework you found many similar Java classes. 
Also you can use in wxWidgets the wxCalendarCtrl class.

Comment: Thanks! That's the kind of answers I'm looking for. Have you ever used it? What are their good/bad points?

Comment: I have developed using Qt for over 4 years. Qt is a very extensive framework. However if it was only to add date functionality I would avoid this because Qt will take some time to learn.

Comment: See http://qt.digia.com/. Is a cross-platform framework, you can develop application with graphical interface using widgets. For developing different projects you can use QCreator or Qt plugin for Eclipse. Is a long discussion if you put the problem to compare different features provided by this API with similar in others.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am unfamiliar with the date / time support in Java so I can not compare the differences I would consider Boost.Date_Time.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/date_time.html