# Use Date and Time in c++

Tags: c++, date, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ standard date/time class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650715/c-standard-date-time-class)

I want to know how to use the date and time with the appropriate data types in c++. Is there any inbuilt functions for calculating the date and time difference etc. Is there any data type which supports this kind of operation?? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this thread, it will help you out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650715/c-standard-date-time-class

Comment: What research have you performed? This has been asked and answered already, many times.

Comment: Thank you @KerrekSB.. came to know about new concept of boost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For C++11, have a look at [Chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono)

For C++03, the same can be found in [Boost.Chrono](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/chrono.html)

Comment: time_t has helped me to resolve the issue. Thanks for your reply. i m very new to the boost. but came to know new things. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with "normal" c++03 not adding any external library you can also give an eye to C's time.h although it's not Object Oriented if you have to do just simple thing it can be handy

Comment: No, if you want to go with C++03 you use C++03, not C. i.e. `<ctime>` not `<time.h>`